# Another idiom for computer programmers

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

One of my (many) mottos:

```
private const success:int = 0;  
attempt(success);  
private function attempt(success:int):void {
    success = success;  
    do {  
        TRY(success);  
    } while (success < 1);
}  

private function TRY(success:int):void {  
    trace("try",success);  
    success += 1;  
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
try 0  
try 0  
try 0  
try 0  
try 0
```

...ad infinitum

Comment: Does this language pass by reference or by value by default? :)

Comment: The language is ActionScript 3, it passes by reference by default.

Comment: I actually implemented this code in an SWF and now have  edited the question to reflect the results.

Comment: @Chowzen I attempted to format your code using the Code formatting tools provided by the editor. The edit currently is in peer review, but in case it doesn't come through (or anyone else wants to use code in their question or answer), you can use 4 spaces at the start of your line to tell the text editor to use a fixed-width font and preserve formatting. it means you don't have to use nested quote formatting.

Comment: @Nzall Thanks. I am new to this site (less than a week) and *have* seen the preformatted text formatting instructions but neglected to utilize the feature. Someone corrected this for me.

Comment: Using `+=` with a `const` makes me instantly hate this language.

Comment: Except the `+=` is being used on a local variable that has not been declared as a `const`.

Comment: why do you expect the code print anything other than 0? In the TRY method what is getting incremented is the local variable success. The parameter effectively shielded the access of the class member

Comment: @Dancrumb, the poster of this question has verified that it is passed _by reference_, not _by value_, meaning that this local variable is a reference to the original constant, implying that it should also be constant (or that `+=` would act to increment a memory address, which is also gross).

Comment: "In ActionScript 3.0, all arguments are passed by reference, because all values are stored as objects. However, objects that belong to the primitive data types, which includes Boolean, Number, int, uint, and String, have special operators that make them behave as if they were passed by value."  Near as I can tell from a quick read of the spec, it's basically the same as Java.  More at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html

Comment: This should be submitted to Nihilist Memes

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell: Whoa, that is abysmally bad. So, just to clear up any confusion: ActionScript 3 is *pass-by-value*, more precisely *call-by-sharing*, *call-by-object*, or *call-by-object-sharing* (which is a special case of pass-by-value). It is *not* pass-by-reference. It has the same semantics as ECMAScript and JavaScript (which is not surprising considering that AS3 is an implementation of the abandoned ES4 and a close cousin to the equally abandoned JS2), and also Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, Java, C♯ (without `ref` or `out`), or pointers in C. The statement in the spec is just wrong. Yuck.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is it:

> If at first you don't succeed, try try again? or alternatively No matter how many times you try you will never succeed

New Reasoning:

> The success variable is a const so it will never change (as shown in the output). That leads me to believe it is if at first you don't succeed try try again, as it will infinitely loop calling the Try method, and succeed is always 0, which is some language represents false (the "don't")

Old Reasoning:

> If the language is pass by value, try will keep being called since you will never succeed (success never actually becomes 1)
>  If the language is pass by reference, try will be called once, and then you break out of the while loop so i'm not sure about this one

Comment: I don't think so.  Based on my quick analysis, this code will never succeed.

Comment: Depends if it is pass by reference or value, if it is reference, try will be called once and then the while passes, if value it will try forever

Comment: Which is why I asked that question :)

Comment: The edit should tell you which it is :)

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's by value or reference.  If it's by value, then the value gets lost at the end of TRY.  However, if it's by reference, then both methods would be passing by reference, and it wouldn't change, due to the constant value of the variable.  Regardless of language setting, this value's never going to chance, from what I see.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha  Yes, this is what I intended when I chose **const** as my variable type. +1

Comment: @LeppyR64 - Hey, this code *might* succeed.  All you have to do is wait for a stray bit of cosmic radiation to flip that memory location to true...

Comment: This was the original concept: **If at first you don't succeed, try, try again.** There were a lot of good answers here, I especially liked "No matter how hard you try, you will never succeed if you don't define "success" correctly" and the Yoda one. :)

Comment: It does, in fact, "try `Try` again".

Comment: Oh, honorable mention to the Insanity one... made me laugh!!

Answer (score 29):

My guess is:

> The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again expecting different results.

Beacuse:

> If the code is pass-by-value then success+=1 within TRY increases the local variable but will not increase the variable in attempt, therefore the while loop will never exit.

Comment: I like the answer, but not the justification. I think the `const` is the part that makes it fail, here. And, you know, constant kinda are always the same thing.

Comment: @Édouard When the answer was posted we didn't have all the information about what language it was.  Later when that was revealed it was clear that Gordon's answer was the correct one.

Comment: When i posted my comment, Gordon’s answer was lacking any justification.

Answer (score 17):

My bet is (sorry for the poor formulation) :

> No matter how hard you try, you will never succeed if you don't define "success" correctly

Explanation :

> I don't know ActionScript, but it seems like the only thing blocking success from happening is that you defined it as a constant value equals 0. No matter what, a const cannot change value => infinite tries => no success :(

Answer (score 6):

My guess is:

> "Do or do not, there is no try." -Yoda

Reasoning:

> Yoda's point was that in order to succeed you must believe in yourself and commit fully. To doubt oneself by only considering the attempt as "trying" is fruitless. In the program, calling TRY does not meaningfully affect success, because when TRY is called the success variable in the outer context remains 0 and the loop is not broken. The only thing that will achieve success and complete the program is by modifying success in the do block, or in other words, by doing.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is

> Do until you die
>
>  the `do` loop keep on **attempt/executes** until it **success/die**

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

> Nothing ventured, nothing gained.

Explanation:

> "try 0" means "try nothing", that is, "venture nothing", and nothing is gained from this program as it never terminates.

Comment: The programmer isn't instructing the program to "try 0,"  "try 0" is merely the output, the result of the executed code. It would be more appropriate to say that "try 0" means "I tried and got a result of nothing."

Answer (score 4):

I have a motto

> "You lose some, you lose some" I never win at anything.
>
>  Pretty much, this code replicates my life. If I win this, that will be an oxymoron, if I don't the code is true.

Answer (score 4):

As a software developer who has worked at or otherwise helped a start-up or two, this immediately reminded me of a quote I've heard at a few of them:

> Samuel Beckett, from *Westward Ho*: "Ever tried. Ever failed. No matter. Try again. Fail again. Fail better.". 
> As every time I hear it I think: "Have you ever seen the rest of that piece or his other stuff? This was not a call to success this was a call to the hopelessness of *constant* failure (0)."

A more complete quote btw:

> "*Ever tried. Ever failed. No matter. Try again. Fail again. Fail better.* Or better worse. Fail worse again. Still worse again. Till sick for good. Throw up for good. Go for good.” 
> With the last part being a reference to how this program will fail until it either runs out of memory, overflows, or is otherwise killed off

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> Never stop trying, because the program will execute "try" forever. SafetySuit agrees with me.

Comment: Who (or what?) is SafetySuit?

Comment: @LeppyR64 A band. They had a song by that name.

Answer (score 2):

> Whosoever desires constant success must change his conduct with the times. – Niccolò Machiavelli

.

> The only way to achieve constant success is to be yourself not constant - if you only try the same thing every time, you will fail.